# Trying to pass variable in url

Tags: php, url

I'm echoing this form:

```
 echo "<form action='/leaguemaster/fichaTorneio.php?id=" . $_GET['torneioid'] . "'>";
```

When I submit the form and it links to the page from the action, the variable I'm passing doesn't reach the page...

```
/leaguemaster/fichaTorneio.php?
```

I've done this in other pages and it worked, I don't know what's going on here. I've tried having the same form outside a PHP echo and I get the same result.

-EDIT-

This is the full form:

```
echo "<form method='GET' action='/leaguemaster/fichaTorneio.php?id= " . $_GET['torneioid'] . "'>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Voltar'>";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: Please try this :-`echo "<form action=/leaguemaster/fichaTorneio.php?id= '". $_GET['torneioid'] . "'>";` check once and tell what happen?

Comment: Same thing, the variable doesn't get through.

Comment: Nope, I don't think its a problem with the " or ' '. I think I've checked those enough times.

Comment: Can you put your code  here please?

Comment: echo "<form method='GET' action='/leaguemaster/fichaTorneio.php?id= " . $_GET['torneioid'] . "'>";
    echo "<input type='submit' value='Voltar'>";
    echo "</form>";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use hidden *type* form's element named `id`:

```
 echo "<form action=\"/leaguemaster/fichaTorneio.php\">";
 echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=\"$_GET[torneioid]\" />"
```

**Notice**: *I did not set the `method` attribute to the form because the GET method is the default method for HTML forms and it makes the form submits its values through the URL query string.*

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that you should check:

> $_GET['torneioid']

This indicates that you are attempting to resolve form or other variables through GET. Make sure that you are passing information through GET and not POST.

Also make sure there is something that is actually stored in torneioid, and that the form or database that you are 'GETting' from, actually holds a value.

Comment: Everything looks fine, the GET is getting a value (1), everything seems well put together. The annoying thing is event if I just do fichaTorneio.php?id=1, it still doesn't do anything.

Comment: To be clear, what you are saying is that echo "<form action='/leaguemaster/fichaTorneio.php?id=" . $_GET['torneioid'] . "'>"; looks fine, but when you click on it, whatever information you are passing doesn't go through? In which case, have you tried adding the method and name fields to your form? E.g. <form method="get" action='/leaguemaster/fichaTorneio.php?id=" . $_GET['torneioid'] . "'>

Comment: Yes, it has a method="GET".

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
 // check $_GET['torneioid'] value
 echo 'torneioid = ' . $_GET['torneioid'] . '<br />';

 echo '<form action="/leaguemaster/fichaTorneio.php?id=' . $_GET['torneioid'] . '">';
```

And make sure the URL contains "http:// yourdomain.com/?torneioid=something"

Comment: torneioid = 1, the value of $_GET['torneioid'] comes from the url of the page where I have the problematic form: /leaguemaster/torneioJogo.php?equipaleft=9&equiparight=12&torneioid=1